# Changing size of flex item doesnt reduce the other flex item size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I the below code i have tried change the font size of flex items. On increasing the font size i expect the corresponding flex-item to occupy the entire parent container height and hide the remaining flex items. But flex item height is stopped to increase at a certain point and the content starts hidden.

current:

[image: Current Behavior]

Expected:

[image]

```css
.parent-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
font-family: 'Heebo';
font-size:35px;
}

.header-container {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.value-container {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.footer-container {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent-container">
<div class="header-container">
<span class="value-span">Header</span>
</div>
<div class="value-container">
<span class="value-span">75</span>
</div>
<div class="footer-container">
<span class="value-span">Footer</span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I think might work is to set `flex-shrink` programmatically to the inverted font size value as the font size changes.

```
function getFontSize(el) {
  return parseInt(
      el.style.fontSize
      || getComputedStyle(el).fontSize
    );
}

// call this whenever font size changes
function updateFlex(flexItems) {
  flexItems.forEach(el => {
    const size = getFontSize(el);
    el.style.flexShrink = 1/size;
  });
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyvyys/52qyhj1f/29/).

You'll have to work on getting those overflow and ellipsis properties to work.

Comment: i want the flex item to occupy the entire container height if i increase the font size of any flex item. If i increase the font size of the value footer container then it occupy the entire container height. In the attached image i have increase the font size of value container.

Comment: Your expectations are a bit fuzzy. What do you mean by "increase font size"? From what value to what? I don't think what you're aiming at is possible with CSS solely. Will the font size be dynamic? I updated the answer to work on `.value-container` instead of `.header-container`.

Comment: Yes.. the font size will be dynamic and the behavior should be same for all the containers. If i increase value font size, then the corresponding container should increase similarly for header.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's what you want.

have you tried to change

```
.value-container{
   overflow:visible;
 }
```